# Need JAD file for blackberry installation

Tags: blackberry, cordova, sencha-touch, jad

I have successful run my app built with phonegap and sencha touch on a Blackberry simulator using the ["How To Create a PhoneGap Plugin for BlackBerry WebWorks"](http://wiki.phonegap.com/w/page/35799737/How%20To%20Create%20a%20PhoneGap%20Plugin%20for%20BlackBerry%20WebWorks) tutorial.

Now I want to run the app on the blackberry device. Should I sign the app no matter what the permissions it is using. And where can I find the JAD file after building the app? Is there any easy method that I can install the app on the blackberry?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Build provided by Phonegap(https://build.phonegap.com/), you will need to make an account and then u can create builds for multiple platforms by uploading your www folder.